# python-firebase get items when added

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I am working with `python-firebase` at the moment, and I have been working with JavaScript and Firebase before. In JS there was the `ref.on('child_added')`, but I am looking to do the same with `python-firebase` (I have to check firebase each time a node is added, so I assume I would need something like this).

So how exactly can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Using [Firebase's REST API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/) (which is what their python API is under the hood), you save the elements using a POST request, which returns the ids of the added elements, so persist that somewhere. Retrieve your elements and iterate through them for the relevant id:

```
# assume your instance is called phones and your username is jack, change as appropriate
def get_object(newest_id):
    objects = requests.get('https://samplechat.firebaseio-demo.com/users/jack/phones.json').json()
    added_object = [obj for obj in objects if obj == newest_id][0]
    return added_object

def add_object(dictionary_representing_object):
    newest_id = requests.post('https://samplechat.firebaseio-demo.com/users/jack/phones.json', json=json.dumps(dictionary_representing_object), verify=False).json()['name']
    stored_object = get_object(newest_id) # stored_object will be a superset of what's in dictionary_representing_object -- it will have an additional entry representing firebase's unique id
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but will I not have to call that over and over again, or does it does itself once some item is added? The idea is to send a notification once a record is added

Comment: Effectively, a listener is a serverside process that does what I outlined.

Answer (score 1):

@hd1's answer works and uses the python-firebase library you already use. But as you say, it will indeed have to poll for updates.

An alternative would be to listen for [Firebase's REST streaming API](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-03-24-streaming-for-firebase-rest-api.html). There is a [Python example of how to consume the REST events](https://github.com/firebase/EventSource-Examples/tree/master/python) (using the Python request and sseclient libraries). The read loop is [here](https://github.com/firebase/EventSource-Examples/blob/master/python/chat.py#L68-L84):

```
        self.sse = ClosableSSEClient(URL)
        for msg in self.sse:
            msg_data = json.loads(msg.data)
            if msg_data is None:    # keep-alives
                continue
            path = msg_data['path']
            data = msg_data['data']
            if path == '/':
                # initial update
                if data:
                    keys = data.keys()
                    keys.sort()
                    for k in keys:
                        self.message_queue.put(data[k])
            else:
                # must be a push ID
                self.message_queue.put(data)
```

While it is not as simple as the native JavaScript client that you've used before, it's as close as you can get to that functionality in Python.